# Spring security core - custom error redirect url

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

I created a custom login form. I am using spring security core plugin for handling user registration and login.

My problem is when user tries to login with wrong username or password. He is still redirected to standard `/login/auth?login_error=1`.

I would like to redirect it to something like `/?login_error=`.

I tried to add

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.failureHandler.defaultFailureUrl = '/'
```

to my application.groovy.

But it doesnt work. Do you know how to to it properly?

Comment: what versions are you using?

Comment: Spring security core 3.1.1 and grails 3.1.9.

Comment: Have you restarted your app after setting that property. Also, have you tried adding the same in `application.yml`?

Comment: Yes I restarted my app. I did not try to add it to application.yml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I skipped this task and added more plugins. After I finished it, this problem disappeared. So either `grails clean` or `gradle refresh dependencies` made it work.